# Free tool to view millimeter coordinate under mouse of a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, measurement, latex

I am looking for a free tool (Windows/Linux) which can display a PDF and show the coordinates under the mouse pointer in millimeter (or inch/etc just what the settings are) based on the PDF coordinate system. It would be nice if it comes with a zoom function for extra precision.

Background is that I want to check (pdflatex) placement of objects in the PDF output.

I found [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971243/tool-for-watching-coordinates-in-pdf) however the answers are not free tools (Illustrator) or pixel based solutions (GIMP), etc.

Comment: Would you accept a grid overlay on your image made with ghostscript?

Comment: Yes how to do it? So PDF in, add vertical/horizontal lines on specific locations (in mm) and output PDF so I can check objects are within the lines. How to do this? I don't want a full grid because if want to check on mm I need to grid every mm and then I get too much lines..

Comment: I am interpretting this as no then. Have you read [this](http://superuser.com/questions/16325/how-to-measure-a-distance-on-a-pdf). many pdf viewers have a protractor tool that can achieve much the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.0 you can do that with [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer.html).

Just tested it. Works great. Changelog said:

> added a document measurement UI. Press 'm' to start. Keep pressing 'm'
>   to change measurement units

You'll find the UI appearing in a box on the top left. Units are mm, in, pt.

Have fun meassuring.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat does this.....

[image]

And Acrobat also has a **Loupe Tool**....

[image]

And you can use both at the same time....

[image]

<sub>Screen shots from Acrobat Pro X, but I can't imagine they've removed these features from newer versions (I just don't like the newer versions).</sub>

Acrobat isn't free.. and I don't know if Reader has these features. But you did tag the question with Acrobat, not Reader.